# Is it a good practice to raise a PR from the merged branch again? if not, why?

Tags: git

There is a small change which I missed but the feature branch that I was working on, got merged to the master. Is it a good idea to continue making changes on the same branch or create a new branch from the master and raise a PR?

I have two options but I am confused. Want to know good practice.

Comment: Ask one of your senior devs what is considered "good practice" at your shop. Everyone out there will have a different answer ... and hence the reason why your question in about to be closed as off-topic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it's generally a good idea to create a new branch from the master to to keep git history clean, a new branch allows to isolate new change and work on it separately.